# R errorbar and polygon with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon

I have a problem using polygon with ggplot. I plot some model predictions and observations (mean and confidence level), and I want to plot a polygon for my observation's confidence level. Here is my data

```
Mat_ic_mu=matrix(c(-3.347582, -3.297287, -3.333237, -3.206484, -3.313200,
-3.313200,-3.313200,-3.313200,-3.355346, -3.315213, -3.354656, -3.252734,
-3.328607, -3.328607, -3.328607, -3.328607,-3.363109, -3.333138,
-3.376076, -3.298983, -3.344014, -3.344014, -3.344014,
-3.344014),ncol=3,nrow=8)

modelName=c("model 1","model 2","model 3","model 0")
type=rep(c("Pred modèle", "Obs"), each = 4)
boxdata=data.frame(Mat_ic_mu,modelName,type)
colnames(boxdata)=c("icp","pred","icm","model","type")

ggplot(boxdata, aes(x = model, y = pred, ymax = icp, ymin = icm, 
                    group = type, colour = type, shape = type)) +
  geom_errorbar(width=0.20) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(name="legend",values=c(19, 4)) +
  scale_color_manual(name="legend",values = c("orange","deepskyblue")) +
  xlab("modèles") + 
  ylab("intervalle de confiance")+
  ggtitle(paste("Intervalle de confiance en ",end_year+1," pour ",Pays_a_predire," âge " , age_bp+start_age-1,sep=""))
```

What I want is adding `polygon` for my Obs, but so long I couldn't figure out a way to add `geom_polygon` to my code.

The resulting figure is as follows:

[image: confidence level]

but what I really want is something more like this :

[image: polygon confidence level]
using `polygon` to create the confidence level, with the mean in the middle

Comment: I suggest using `geom_ribbon` and `geom_line`.

Comment: Can you please suggest a way to use them ? The main problem is that I don't know what to put as argument for data, and for aes

Comment: Your example data gives me a completely different plot. (observed and predicted are the same)

Comment: I have modified the data, can you please consider the updated one, it should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `geom_line` and `geom_ribbon`, we need to subset the data to our layers:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = model, y = pred, ymax = icp, ymin = icm)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(group = 1), data = subset(boxdata, type == "Obs"), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(group = 1), data = subset(boxdata, type == "Obs")) +
  geom_errorbar(data = subset(boxdata, type == "Pred modèle"), width = 0.20) +
  geom_point(data = subset(boxdata, type == "Pred modèle"))
```

[image]